# Solve this contour integral with three roots, one outside

Tags: complex-analysis

What I have is $\int_{C[0, 3]} \frac{dz}{(z + 4)(z + i)(z - i)}$ and I know that there are poles at $-4, -i, i$. However, I do not think it is kosher to simply state that $\int_{C[0, 3]} \frac{dz}{(z + 4)(z + i)(z - i)} = \int_{C[0, 3]} \frac{dz}{(z + i)(z - i)}.$ If it is, correct me.

Now I evaluate this integral thus

$\int_{C[0, 3]} \frac{dz}{(z + 4)(z + i)(z - i)}$ = $\int_{C[0, 3]} \frac{\frac{1}{z+4}}{(z + i)(z - i)} dz$ = $\int_{C[-i, R_1]} \frac{f_1(z)}{(z + i)} dz + \int_{C[i, R_2]} \frac{f_2(z)}{(z - i)}$. However, I cannot find out the correct values for $f_1, f_2$. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What does $C[0,3]$ mean?

Comment: A circle in the complex plane centered at 0 with radius 3.

Comment: Why don't you use the residue theorem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint. Use [Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula): for $r>0$ (and $r<2$)
$$\int_{C(0, 3)} \frac{dz}{(z + 4)(z + i)(z - i)}=\int_{C(-i, r)} \frac{f_1(z)}{(z + i)} dz + \int_{C(i, r)} \frac{f_2(z)}{(z - i)}=2\pi i f_1(-i)+2\pi i f_2(i)$$
where $f_1(z)=\frac{1}{(z + 4)(z - i)}$ and $f_2(z)=\frac{1}{(z + 4)(z + i)}$.